# Run formula only If cell contains a value

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Microsoft Office 365. I'd like to do something like

```
=(SUM(J4:J20)+K23)/G23
```

but sometimes `K23` doesn't have a value. So I'm thinking I need to say only do `+K23` if it contains a value.

How would I do that?

Comment: @slhck Thank you for showing me how to better ask my question.

Comment: Do you want the division by `G23` to apply to the sum of `J4:J20` if `K23` has no value? I know that's not what the formula says, just checking

Comment: @Raystafarian Yes

Comment: You should change your requested formula to indicate that like `=(sum(J:J)+K)/G)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

`=SUM(J4:J20,IF(K23<>"",K23))/G23`

Unless sometimes `G23` is blank or zero, replace `/G23` with `/if(G23<>"",G23,1)`

Comment: Right now I'm using =SUM(J4:J20,IF(K23<>"",K23))/if(G23<>"",G23,1)  ... Is it possible to say if G23 is blank or 0 then abort/don't do anything/exit/don't even do =SUM ??

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to use any `IF` conditions here. Just include `K23` in the `SUM` function. `SUM` will ignore any non-numeric, non-error values, so it doesn't matter if K23 is blank.

```
 =SUM(J4:J20,K23)/G23
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

With Office 365 you could use [IFError()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/iferror-function-HA010342587.aspx) like

```
=SUM(J4:J20)+IFERROR(K23/G23,0)
```

ISError() works differently and the earlier suggestion will present an error. You can still use ISError(), but it would need to be nested in an IF() statement:

```
=SUM(J4:J20)+IF(ISERROR(K23/G23),0,K23/G23)
```

This will mean that the division is carried out twice, which is slower than the IFError(), where it is only calculated once.

Comment: I'm looking for (J4:J20) which is $17.20 + $23.70 + $78.00 then plus K23, if there is a value (which in this case is $20), then divide it all by G23 which is 130.... So using my calculator that should be $1.07. And the formula your giving me comes up with $119.05?

Comment: Ah, I started with the suggested IsError formula, which had the concept wrong. Never mind.

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to do something similar, but leaving a cumulative column blank unless a reference column had data while subtracting from another column if it had data.

=IF(B6=0,"",SUM(D5)+(B6)-(C6))

Comment: (1) This doesn’t really seem to be what the question is asking for.  (2) The question has been adequately answered.  (3) There’s no reason to say `SUM(D5)`; it’s equivalent to `D5`. Likewise, `SUM(D5)+(B6)-(C6)` is equivalent to `D5+B6-C6`.

Answer (score -2):

=if(k23=0,"", function)

the first part of an if function is the logical test (i.e. is a certain cell blank)

the second part (after the first comma) says to leave answer blank (notice, there's nothing between the quote marks)

the third part (after the second comma) is where you type your normal function...

Comment: This doesn't look like a complete answer... Can you expand on it?

Comment: opps! I had it wrong at first! updated answer should work!!